# Unable to find any information about TLB on my computer or obtain information about hardware counters about TLB

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu, intel, perf, perf-event

The Ubuntu version I am using is **Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS**,  and the kernel version is **5.4.0-148 generic**. My processor  is **12th Gen Intel (R) Core (TM) i7-12700**.

I would like to know the number of TLB entries in my CPU for different page sizes (1G, 2MB, 4KB), as well as the number of dTLB misses during program execution.

`cpuid -1` command told me they are 0：

```
    L1 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/eax):
      instruction # entries     = 0x0 (0)
      instruction associativity = 0x0 (0)
      data # entries            = 0x0 (0)
      data associativity        = 0x0 (0)
   L1 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/ebx):
      instruction # entries     = 0x0 (0)
      instruction associativity = 0x0 (0)
      data # entries            = 0x0 (0)
      data associativity        = 0x0 (0)
   L1 data cache information (0x80000005/ecx):
      line size (bytes) = 0x0 (0)
      lines per tag     = 0x0 (0)
      associativity     = 0x0 (0)
      size (KB)         = 0x0 (0)
   L1 instruction cache information (0x80000005/edx):
      line size (bytes) = 0x0 (0)
      lines per tag     = 0x0 (0)
      associativity     = 0x0 (0)
      size (KB)         = 0x0 (0)
   L2 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/eax):
      instruction # entries     = 0x0 (0)
      instruction associativity = L2 off (0)
      data # entries            = 0x0 (0)
      data associativity        = L2 off (0)
   L2 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/ebx):
      instruction # entries     = 0x0 (0)
      instruction associativity = L2 off (0)
      data # entries            = 0x0 (0)
      data associativity        = L2 off (0)
   L2 unified cache information (0x80000006/ecx):
      line size (bytes) = 0x40 (64)
      lines per tag     = 0x0 (0)
      associativity     = 0x7 (7)
      size (KB)         = 0x500 (1280)
   L3 cache information (0x80000006/edx):
      line size (bytes)     = 0x0 (0)
      lines per tag         = 0x0 (0)
      associativity         = L2 off (0)
      size (in 512KB units) = 0x0 (0)
```

`perf stat -e dTLB-loads,dTLB-load-misses,iTLB-load-misses` shows not supported

UPDATE：

```
$ cpuid -1 -l 2
CPU:
      0xff: cache data is in CPUID 4
      0xfe: unknown
      0xf0: 64 byte prefetching

$ cpuid -1 -l 0x18
CPU:
   0x00000018 0x00: eax=0x00000004 ebx=0x00000000 ecx=0x00000000 edx=0x00000000

$ perf -v
perf version 5.4.231


$ perf list

List of pre-defined events (to be used in -e):

  branch-instructions OR branches                    [Hardware event]
  branch-misses                                      [Hardware event]
  bus-cycles                                         [Hardware event]
  cache-misses                                       [Hardware event]
  cache-references                                   [Hardware event]
  cpu-cycles OR cycles                               [Hardware event]
  instructions                                       [Hardware event]
  ref-cycles                                         [Hardware event]

  alignment-faults                                   [Software event]
  bpf-output                                         [Software event]
  context-switches OR cs                             [Software event]
  cpu-clock                                          [Software event]
  cpu-migrations OR migrations                       [Software event]
  dummy                                              [Software event]
  emulation-faults                                   [Software event]
  major-faults                                       [Software event]
  minor-faults                                       [Software event]
  page-faults OR faults                              [Software event]
  task-clock                                         [Software event]
```

I'm completely confused about what's wrong with my machine.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there’s anything wrong with your machine. `cpuid`’s output is raw and needs some interpretation; specifically, for TLB information, [you should look at the leaf 2 information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58128776/4500798) rather than the section you quoted. You’ll find that further up in the output, or you can ask for it directly:

```
$ cpuid -1 -l 2
CPU:
      0x63: data TLB: 2M/4M pages, 4-way, 32 entries
            data TLB: 1G pages, 4-way, 4 entries
      0x03: data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way, 64 entries
      0x76: instruction TLB: 2M/4M pages, fully, 8 entries
      0xff: cache data is in CPUID leaf 4
      0xb5: instruction TLB: 4K, 8-way, 64 entries
      0xf0: 64 byte prefetching
      0xc1: L2 TLB: 4K/2M pages, 8-way, 1024 entries
```

As far as `perf` is concerned, the version you have might not know about your CPU (I haven’t checked).

Comment: I tried this command and updated the results in the question. Unfortunately, there is still no information about TLB.

Additionally, from the`perf list`, it can collect events such as cache misses, which should be able to know my CPU.

Do you think this is caused by my machine (hardware) or system (software)? I am considering whether installing the latest Ubuntu and kernel will solve this problem.

Comment: Ah, your CPU reports a value for 0xFE in leaf 2, which means that the TLB information is in leaf 0x18 (`cpuid -1 -l 0x18`). `perf` can indeed collect cache misses, but that doesn’t imply that it should know about your CPU — the 5.4 series was first released in late 2019, quite a while before details of 12th gen CPUs were available. In general, good support for 12th gen requires at least version 5.16 of the kernel, so at least version 5.16 of `perf` (which is tied to the kernel).